# Persisting unlinked object throws: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to persist an object using JPA but I keep getting this error: `During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST`. The weird thing is, if I press the button to persist the object, the first time it gives this error, and after that it works perfectly.

**EDIT**
I Have found that even removing the `em.persist(doelstelling);` line does not fix the issuae, so I would guess there is still something waiting to be commited?

(Classes are simplified)

Categorie.java:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class Categorie implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(unique=true, nullable = false)
    private String naam;
    
    @Lob
    private byte[] icoon;


// This was not commented first, but commenting did not really help and the problem persists
//  @ManyToMany
//  private Set<MvoDoelstelling> doelstellingen;
    private Set<Rol> rollen;
    
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "categorie",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
        )
    private Set<Sdg> sdgs;

}
```

Doelstelling.java

```java
@Entity
public class MvoDoelstelling extends MvoDoelstellingComponent {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Transient
    private PropertyChangeSupport support;
    
// Commented this aswell to try and eliminate all lists but no succes
//  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//  private List<MvoDoelstellingComponent> mvoDoelstellingComponenten;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Sdg sdg;
    
    
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private double drempelWaarde;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Set<Rol> rollen;
    
    @Lob
    private byte[] icoon;
}
```

Code to save:

```java
    @Override
    public void saveDoelstelling(MvoDoelstelling doelstelling) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(doelstelling);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

persistence.xml

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="xxx" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>domein.Gebruiker</class>
    <class>domein.AanmeldPoging</class>
    <class>domein.Categorie</class>
    <class>domein.Sdg</class>
    <class>domein.MvoDoelstelling</class>
    <class>domein.MvoDoelstellingComponent</class>
    <class>domein.Datasource</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I do think it might have something to do with the Sdg that gets saved in both classes and maybe has a reference like that?

Comment: Where is the em reference coming from? Anything read through it will be managed and changes to managed entities will get picked up in the transaction. You might try calling em.clear(), but it’s better long term to make sure you manage the scope of EntityManagers

Comment: The em is just a global EntityManager, it has detached the categorie object, and by randomly calling the transaction begin and end method, throws the error. I have noticed however that this happens because the SDG class gets updated and there is a reference to that, I will update the question

Comment: That is your problem - using a global EntityManager. They are not thread safe, and hold onto EVERYTHING read through it. You are randomly starting transitions and making everything it finds in its current state be persisted to the database. Get a new Entitymanager for transactional operations - that is the point of them.

Comment: Wait no sorry I think I was wrong, I have an interface `GenericDao` with a static final `EntityManager`, and for each class a repo is created which inherits `GenericDeo`. So I am guessing it's fine then? Or should I create a new one for each transaction?

Comment: Static final? That is one unchanging instance used within ALL implementing classes. It is not what you want. let the container inject it (if you are within a container), or obtain one on demand from the EntityManagerFactory (which is safer to be in a static final variable).

Comment: Ah yea, the factory is indeed also a static final, so It shouldn't be difficult to implement it!

Comment: So I do create a new EntityManager for each transaction then or just have a private var in each implementation?

Comment: Check out a JPA tutorial that explains RESOURCE_LOCAL, but yes, you should be using a new EntityManager for each transaction. They are meant to represent units of work, so be short lived and are not thread safe, so you can't share one among processes at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242932/discussion-between-jasper-b-and-chris).